# Trying to convert a seaborn plot function

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to create a line plot in seaborn and the below code works perfectly fine.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(50, 50))
fig1 = sns.lineplot(data=zrrgroupbysummary, x='filedate', y='Count', hue='location', 
style='location', linewidth=3.0)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Resource Count')
plt.title(f'Trend - By SBU\n {dt.date.strftime(fromdate, "%m/%d/%Y")} to {dt.date.strftime(todate, 
"%m/%d/%Y")}')
fig1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
fig1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO))
fig1.grid(True, which='minor', lw=1, ls=':', color='darkgrey')
fig1.grid(True, which='major', lw=1, color='darkgrey')
```

However when I make the above into a function and try to plot I get the below error

```
titlee = f'Trend - By SBU\n {dt.date.strftime(fromdate, "%m/%d/%Y")} to 
{dt.date.strftime(todate, 
"%m/%d/%Y")}'
Summary_Reporting('rrgroupbysummary',"'filedate'","'Count'","'location'", 
"'location'", titlee, 
'fig1')
```

The function:

```
def Summary_Reporting(data, xaxis, yaxis, hue, style, titlee, fig):
    print(f'{fig} = sns.lineplot(data = {data}, x = {xaxis}, y={yaxis}, hue = 
    {hue}, style={style})')
    plt.figure()
    fig = sns.lineplot(data=data, x=xaxis, y=yaxis, hue=hue, style=style, 
    linewidth=3.0)
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Resource Count')
    plt.title(titlee)
    fig.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
    fig.xaxis.set_minor_locator(WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO))
    fig.grid(True, which='minor', lw=1, ls=':', color='darkgrey')
    fig.grid(True, which='major', lw=1, color='darkgrey')
```

The error I am getting is:

```
fig1 = sns.lineplot(data = rrgroupbysummary, x = 'filedate', y='Count', 
hue = 'location', style='location')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/PYTHON/PyCharm/Python/ZRR_modified.py", line 142, in <module>
Summary_Reporting('rrgroupbysummary',"'filedate'","'Count'","'location'", 
"'location'", titlee, 'fig1')
File "E:/PYTHON/PyCharm/Python/ZRR_modified.py", line 35, in 
Summary_Reporting
fig = sns.lineplot(data=data, x=xaxis, y=yaxis, hue=hue, style=style, 
linewidth=3.0)
File "C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 1120, in lineplot
p = _LinePlotter(
File "C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 694, in __init__
plot_data = self.establish_variables(
File "C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 126, in establish_variables
x = data.get(x, x)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

If you see the print statement is perfectly fine but still not sure why getting the error

Comment: Try: `x=data[xaxis]` and `y=data[yaxis]`

Comment: Changing to fig = sns.lineplot(data=data,x=data[xaxis], y=data[yaxis], hue=hue, style=style, linewidth=3.0) gives the below error:                                                                       fig = sns.lineplot(x=data[xaxis], y=data[yaxis], hue=hue, style=style, linewidth=3.0)
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are passing the name of the dataframe to your function, instead of the dataframe itself.

You should be writing (notice the lack of quotes " ' "):

```
Summary_Reporting(rrgroupbysummary,"filedate","Count","location", "location", titlee, fig1)
```

instead of:

```
Summary_Reporting('rrgroupbysummary',"'filedate'","'Count'","'location'", "'location'", titlee, 'fig1')
```

Comment: This is what I tried. Thanks for correcting that I need to pass the dataframe instead of the name of the data frame.
    Summary_Reporting(zrrgroupbysummary,"filedate","Count","location", "location", titlee, "fig1")  Now getting the below error.  ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 6), indices imply (63, 6)

Comment: It's not. Notice that I have removed the single quotes (') from your line

Comment: I did remove the single quotes as you had mentioned above but had  fig1 in double quotes as it is a string. If I remove the quotes the code gives a syntax error.

Comment: I was able to resolve it now. I was asked to put the x and y axis in [ ] bracket above /which resulted in the above error. After removing the [ ] bracket it is now resolved.